# wordpress category page: Custom meta description

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress, and I'm trying to create custom descriptions for categories pages.

I have modified its header.php file to echo custom titles and descriptions. But Wordpress is replacing my meta description with that of first post.

How can I stop this?

My Code:

```
echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$desc.'" />';
```

I'm using eMovies Theme: http://fthemes.com/emovies-free-wordpress-theme/

My site category link: http://www.raagalu.in/category/telugu-songs/

I even tried using plugins like "Category SEO Meta Tags", but no use. It is just creating two meta descriptions.

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php single_cat_title(); ?>
```

If you are on a category or template page.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title